# setVisibile(false) not hiding the frame

Tags: java, swing

Instead it just opens the new frame, and when that one closes.. it not only doesnt hide and go back to the main frame as its supposed to.. it opens a second version of the first frame...

```
public class FreelanceBillingUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {



public FreelanceBillingUI(){
    initComponents();
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jSeparator3 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jSeparator4 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1), "Little Bit of Crazy Design Studio", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Bleeding Cowboys", 0, 48))); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 660, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "State Your Purpose", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Northwood High", 1, 36))); // NOI18N

    jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/my/freelancebillingapp/1256082409_user_female.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            custClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/my/freelancebillingapp/1256081773_coins.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            billClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/my/freelancebillingapp/1256082503_todo_list_remove.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton3.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            paidClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/my/freelancebillingapp/1256082170_invoice.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton4.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            invoiceClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/my/freelancebillingapp/1256082607_user_male_remove.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton5.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            removeClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    jLabel1.setText("Customers");

    jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    jLabel2.setText("Billing");

    jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    jLabel3.setText("Paid Status");

    jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    jLabel4.setText("Invoice");

    jLabel5.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    jLabel5.setText("Remove");

    jSeparator1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));
    jSeparator1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));

    jSeparator2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));

    jSeparator3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));

    jSeparator4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18))
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jSeparator3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jSeparator4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jLabel4))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(60, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                            .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                            .addComponent(jSeparator4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jSeparator3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(42, 42, 42))))
    );

    jLabel6.setText("Copyright Jason Bodary - Little Bit of Crazy Design Studio     Inveniemus viam aut faciemus.");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,  javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,  javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,  layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(165, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel6)
            .addGap(147, 147, 147))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel6)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void custClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    new FreelanceBillingUI().setVisible(false);
    new customerInfoUI().setVisible(true);
}

private void billClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void paidClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void invoiceClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void removeClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/


public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new FreelanceBillingUI().setVisible(true);
            new customerInfoUI().setVisible(false);



        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator3;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator4;
// End of variables declaration

}
```

Comment: Nothing like unreadable NetBeans generated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new FreelanceBillingUI().setVisible(false);
new customerInfoUI().setVisible(true);
```

That's what it is suppose to do, create new frames. You should keep references to your old frames and call `setVisible(false)` on them, not on newly created instances.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

```
private void custClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    new FreelanceBillingUI().setVisible(false);
    new customerInfoUI().setVisible(true);
}
```

Into:

```
private void custClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    this.setVisible(false);
    new customerInfoUI().setVisible(true);
}
```

Because you make in the first code a new instance from `FreelanceBillingUI` by writing 
`new FreelanceBillingUI()`. That new instance who's not visible, make you invisible. So, nothing will happen.

So you have to know what the difference between a new instance (calling a construcor) and a variable.

Answer (score 0):

As Pilgrim already said, you've got a problem because you're not holding an instance to the JFrame that you're creating. You should be doing something like:

```
FreelanceBillingUI frame = newFreelanceBillingUI();
frame.setVisible(true);

... more stuff to do with the frame...

frame.setVisible(false);
```

Why are you trying to make the frame invisible? Are you trying to close it definitively, or you just want to hide it temporarily? Do you want to close the application when the frame is closed? You should take a look at the method `setDefaultCloseOperation` of `JFrame`.

For instance, with the following code you can configure you frame to close the application when the frame is closed:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Take a look at the other possible values (`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`, and `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`).

Comment: Because the program will have 5 different sections, each section has it's own window.  When you go from the main menu to one of the options the main menu window should go away, and when you close the section window the main menu should come back.

Even if I set it to
FreelanceBillingUI frame = newFreelanceBillingUI();
when I call -
frame.setVisible(true);
under the event for the button, it just tells me it cant find the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .dispose(); then call it again.